# python txt file edit using loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, readlines

```
for k in np.arange(200, 600, 5.5):
new_text_content = ''
with open(file_name, "r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    m1 = lines[0]
    m2 = lines[1]
    n1 = '/OutputFile = '  + str(k) 
    n2 = '/BeamEnergy = ' + str(k) 
    #lines[0].writerow(m1)
    file.replace(lines[1], n2)

file.close()
```

i want to change first line and second line like n1, n2 using loop to change value(k). how can i edit my code? The value(k) is increasing until 600 and break.

Comment: put the for loop inside the `with` context manager.

Comment: You file is in read mode. Also I would read the file and save the content like you did. But then I would make my modification outside the context manager. Then You can open you file again but in 'w' mode  and write the content into it

Answer (score 1):

You can put you logic inside a function and then pass whatever values you want for n1 or n2 to the function.

So with a function like this:

```
def your_loop(start, stop, interval):

    for k in np.arange(start, stop, interval):
    new_text_content = ''
    with open(file_name, "r") as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        m1 = lines[0]
        m2 = lines[1]
        n1 = '/OutputFile = '  + str(k)
        n2 = '/BeamEnergy = ' + str(k)
        #lines[0].writerow(m1)
        file.replace(lines[1], n2)
```

You can then call it like this `your_loop(200, 700, 5.5)`. This would create a numpy array that starts at 200, finishes at 500, with intervals of 5.5.

Note as another person has noted, you don't need to close the file since that's handled by the context manager in this line `with open(file_name, "r") as file:`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't have to call close on the file, this is done automatically because you are use the `with` keyword. Next you should open the file with `"r+"` not `"r"`. So you can write to it.

```
for k in np.arange(200, 600, 5.5):
    with open(filename, "r+") as file:
        lines = ['/OutputFile = '  + str(k) + "\n", '/BeamEnergy = ' + str(k) + "\n"]
        file.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! OP's question was about how to change the loop created with arange, not about how to close the file or open it.

Comment: Please check again, this actually fixes your code.